# How do I invoke liquid-rescale with the Paperclip gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using the Paperclip gem with a Rails 3.1.1 app. It's working as advertised and expected. I would like to use the imagemagick `-liquid-rescale` delegate, however. According to the [imagemagick documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#liquid-rescale) (which I tried in terminal.app), this works:

```
convert logo_trimmed.jpg  -liquid-rescale 75x100%\!  logo_lqr.jpg
```

I tried a variation...

```
convert my_pic.jpg -liquid-rescale 60x60\! my_new_pic.jpg
```

That worked as expected, too. I've tried several permutations in my Image model in my rails app, but I cannot get Paperclip to invoke liquid-rescale. My latest attempt was:

```
has_attached_file :pic, :styles => {:square => "-liquid-rescale 60x60\!" }
```

This fails without an error message, merely duplicating the original image with a new name.

How do I instruct paperclip to invoke liquid-rescale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. I had to write a custom processor, which I named `liquid`.In the model:

```
has_attached_file :pic, :styles => {:square => {:processors =>[:liquid],:geometry => "60x60>"} }
```

I'm not sure whether the `:geometry` option is necessary, but I added it because `thumbnail.rb` in the paperclip gem says that it's not optional.

I then added a file: `/my_app/lib/paperclip_processors/liquid.rb` with contents:

```
module Paperclip
    class Liquid < Thumbnail
        def transformation_command
            "-resize '60x60>' -liquid-rescale '60x60!'"
        end
    end
end
```

Finally, I ran the following in the console:

```
Image.all.each {|i| i.pic.reprocess!}
```

That did the trick.